# WEBRTC p2p , javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc

I am  working on a p2p application chat. In this application a user has to be able to establish connection to more than one user ( 2 or 3 others user ) and exchange data . For now, the user can only establish connection with one  peer . if the user try to connect to another one , he will lose the connection to the other user. Do anyone has an idea how I can resolve this problem ?

thanks in advance